# Pandas, columns not in index(beginner)

Tags: python, pandas

what I am trying to do is to get pandas dataframe from CSV file.This is how my file looks like.

```
Date;Open;High;Low;Last Close;Chg.%;Total Value;Total Volume;
"02/10/2017";"29.345";"29.375";"29.005";"29.105";"-0.33%";"32,283,437";"1,106,900";
"02/13/2017";"29.100";"30.050";"29.100";"29.870";"+2.63%";"51,101,636";"1,715,810";
"02/14/2017";"29.710";"30.150";"29.665";"30.100";"+0.77%";"36,702,427";"1,225,914";
"02/15/2017";"30.190";"30.300";"29.865";"29.950";"-0.50%";"42,224,148";"1,406,422";
"02/16/2017";"29.815";"29.940";"29.585";"29.770";"-0.60%";"37,021,299";"1,245,004";
```

And this is formatting I want to achieve.

```
             Open    High         Low      Last Close   Total Volume
Date                                                
2012-05-18  42.050  45.0000     38.0000     38.2318     573576400.0     
2012-05-21  36.530  36.6600     33.0000     34.0300     168192700.0     
2012-05-22  32.610  33.5900     30.9400     31.0000     101786600.0     
2012-05-23  31.370  32.5000     31.3600     32.0000     73600000.0
```

I thought that doing something like this will be sufficient.

```
df = pd.read_csv("/home/tomek/Pobrane/historicalData_AT0000652011.csv")
df = df[['Date','Open',  'High',  'Last Low',  'Close', 'Total Volume]]
```

However, I am getting error

```
"['Date;' 'Open;' 'High;' 'Low;' 'Last Close;' 'Total Volume;'] not in index"
```

`df.columns` allows me to rename only one column, otherwise it says that no such index exists so I think the header is treated as one big column.

So I think I should format my CSV file. However, I am not sure in what way, so it will be readable for pandas.

Thank you for any advice
​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) only with parameters:

- `sep=';'` for separator
- `index_col=['Date']` and `parse_dates=['Date']` for `DatetimeIndex`
- `usecols` for filter columns by list
- `thousands=','` for remove `,`

---

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Date;Open;High;Low;Last Close;Chg.%;Total Value;Total Volume;
"02/10/2017";"29.345";"29.375";"29.005";"29.105";"-0.33%";"32,283,437";"1,106,900";
"02/13/2017";"29.100";"30.050";"29.100";"29.870";"+2.63%";"51,101,636";"1,715,810";
"02/14/2017";"29.710";"30.150";"29.665";"30.100";"+0.77%";"36,702,427";"1,225,914";
"02/15/2017";"30.190";"30.300";"29.865";"29.950";"-0.50%";"42,224,148";"1,406,422";
"02/16/2017";"29.815";"29.940";"29.585";"29.770";"-0.60%";"37,021,299";"1,245,004";"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to '/home/tomek/Pobrane/historicalData_AT0000652011.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep=";", 
                 index_col=['Date'], 
                 parse_dates=['Date'], 
                 usecols=['Date','Open',  'High',  'Low',  'Last Close', 'Total Volume'], 
                 thousands=',')

print (df)
              Open    High     Low  Last Close  Total Volume
Date                                                        
2017-02-10  29.345  29.375  29.005      29.105       1106900
2017-02-13  29.100  30.050  29.100      29.870       1715810
2017-02-14  29.710  30.150  29.665      30.100       1225914
2017-02-15  30.190  30.300  29.865      29.950       1406422
2017-02-16  29.815  29.940  29.585      29.770       1245004
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly pass the separator (";") if its not a *comma separated value* file. So try the following:

```
In [8]: df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')  # should be same like pd.read_csv
In [9]: df.set_index("Date")[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Last Close', 'Total Volume']]
Out[9]:
              Open    High     Low  Last Close Total Volume
Date
02/10/2017  29.345  29.375  29.005      29.105    1,106,900
02/13/2017  29.100  30.050  29.100      29.870    1,715,810
02/14/2017  29.710  30.150  29.665      30.100    1,225,914
02/15/2017  30.190  30.300  29.865      29.950    1,406,422
02/16/2017  29.815  29.940  29.585      29.770    1,245,004
```

Of course you can also directly pass "Date" as index_col via parameter `index_col`:

```
In [1]: pd.read_clipboard(sep=';', index_col="Date", thousands=',')[['Open',  'High',  'Low',  'Last Close', 'Total Volume']]
Out[1]:
              Open    High     Low  Last Close  Total Volume
Date
02/10/2017  29.345  29.375  29.005      29.105       1106900
02/13/2017  29.100  30.050  29.100      29.870       1715810
02/14/2017  29.710  30.150  29.665      30.100       1225914
02/15/2017  30.190  30.300  29.865      29.950       1406422
02/16/2017  29.815  29.940  29.585      29.770       1245004
```